# removing authentication form from our site

Tags: html, .htaccess

I've just had our site done by a developer. www.dppj.fr, its a simple site.
On his machine it works fine but on the server where we host it there is an authentication window that opens up asking for the ID & PW.
We don't want it as viewers don't have a login or PW.
Moreover the login & PW seem to be the ID & PW of the dashboard.

Is it a problem with the server or the developer?

Can anyone help?

Daniel

Comment: check if there's an .htaccess file in the site's home directory and open it up see if its looking for auth.

Comment: Server problem: as you already tagged it with htaccess, and it is in fact a htaccess. if you don't know how to remove it, you should ask your hoster.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are seeing HTTP authentication. Look for a .htaccess file in the root of your public html folder and remove the lines that look like...

```
AuthUserFile /full/path/to/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Secret Folder"
Require valid-user
```

or things that look like...

```
<Files "mypage.html">
  Require valid-user
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the above answers. It appears that only 1 object in the site is causing the request.  I am guessing that you don't want to remove all authentication, but you will need to find out which object/image is requiring the auth. If you have access to the access_logs for the site, look for something with a 401 status code

Comment: Thanks all. @Doon, yes it seems to be in the images as hen we deactivate the images it works OK. NOw I need to get the guy that did the site to modify it. Thanks again, Daniel.